# How to define a Jolt spec that will work for both array and value

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

**Description** I am working on a problem required JSON to JSON conversion, so I am using Jolt library for that. There are some nodes in my input JSON document that can come sometime as array of objects and sometime normal object. I am not able to define a Jolt spec that will work for both array of objects and single object.

**Requirement** If the node contains an array of objects, take the 0th element from the array and map it to the output JSON.

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "patient": {
        "@": "ONE",
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "patient": {
        "dateOfBirth": "patient.dateOfBirth",
        "firstName": "patient.firstName",
        "lastName": "patient.lastName"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Input JSON (JSON Spec works fine for this input)**

```json
{
  "patient": [
    {
      "dateOfBirth": [
        "19890101",
        "19890101"
      ],
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Test"
    },
    {
      "dateOfBirth": [
        "19890101",
        "19890101"
      ],
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output JSON (Getting expected output)**

```json
{
  "patient" : {
    "dateOfBirth" : "19890101",
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "lastName" : "Test"
  }
}
```

**But when the patient is not coming as an array but a single object, then the defined jolt spec is not working anymore.**

**Input JSON (JSON spec is not working for this input)**

```json
{
  "patient": {
    "dateOfBirth": [
      "19890101",
      "19890101"
    ],
    "genderCode": "1",
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Test"
  }
}
```

**Actual Output (Not correct)**

```json
{
  "patient" : {
    "dateOfBirth" : [ "19890101", "19890101" ],
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "lastName" : "Test"
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "patient" : {
    "dateOfBirth" : "19890101",
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "lastName" : "Test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether `patient` is an array or not through use of **modify-beta** transform. In this case, I've used **firstElement** function within that transform. Then, use conditional logic such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "isArray": ["=firstElement(@(1,patient))", "No"]
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(0,isArray)": {
        "No": { "@(2,patient)": "patient" },
        "*": { "@": "patient.&" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

if the attribute `"genderCode"` is not needed, then add an extra **remove** transform such as

```json
,
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "genderCode": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo 1 :
[image]

Demo 2 :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just one thing I noticed that if I use your spec JSON the output is not coming as a patient object. How can I add all the fields like dateOfBirth, firstName, lastName inside patient object like below -
{
  "patient" : {
    "dateOfBirth" : "19890101",
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "lastName" : "Test"
  }
}